# How do I circumvent the versioning system to run an outdated MacOSX application?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, imovie

I have iMovie HD 6.03. I want it to run on Yosemite. The application icon itself has a "circle-slash-do-not-run" icon superimposed on the iMovie icon. When I double click the icon a dialog pops up saying that it can't run.

I can dig into the application package itself and run the actual compiled executable; this tells me that the application itself can run but something in the packaging is preventing iMovie from running.

**How do I tweak the application packaging so that iMovie 6.0.3 can run on Yosemite?** I expect to edit a plist or something.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to different SE sites.

Comment: OK. Can you close this and/or migrate it to askdifferent.stackexchange.com? Sorry.